# Executing SQL Server stored procedure - Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting the following error.

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '@ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds'.*

I have no idea why this is happening.  If I execute the stored procedure directly it works fine.

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC [TEST].[DeleteDivisionBracketPartsTEST]  
@DivisionBracketId 
@ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds 
@MemberId',
N'@DivisionBracketId int,
@ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds nvarchar(max),
@MemberId int',
@DivisionBracketId=145,
@ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds=N'473',
@MemberId=53

ALTER PROCEDURE [TEST].[DeleteDivisionBracketPartsTEST]
    @DivisionBracketId INT,
    @ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @MemberId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Comment: i am not sure but, Is it that you missed commas in the second line after '@DivisionBracketId '.. ?

Comment: You're right, stupid mistake.  Make it an answer and ill mark it.

Comment: you need to define the type for your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the commas After @DivisionBracketId and @ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds.

it should be like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC [TEST].[DeleteDivisionBracketPartsTEST]  
@DivisionBracketId, 
@ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds, 
@MemberId',
N'@DivisionBracketId int,
@ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds nvarchar(max),
@MemberId int',
@DivisionBracketId=145,
@ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds=N'473',
@MemberId=53

ALTER PROCEDURE [TEST].[DeleteDivisionBracketPartsTEST]
    @DivisionBracketId INT,
    @ExcludedDivisionBracketPartIds NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @MemberId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
```